# Android studio app not desplaying corectly on exported .apk

Tags: android, display

so my android studio preview looks like this:
[ScreenShot from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY7Eu.png)

but when i export the app and run it on the phone, it looks like this:
[Screenshot from the actual phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udV1k.png)

Here is my activity_main.xml file text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgr"
        android:layout_width="789dp"
        android:layout_height="778dp"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
        android:text="Welcome to Auth-Guard!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="31sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="304dp"
        tools:textColor="aaa" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/swt_theme"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="Dark Theme"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="539dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the constraints of the button and other views.

Answer (score 0):

As Raj said you should set the constraints of the views correctly. I think you need learn `ConstrainLayout`.

Here is some help: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

and this tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/13590/android-constraintlayout

Comment: yes, but for example, on the button, i have: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       and android:layout_height="wrap_content", is still in the corner. EDIT: i also set the layout width and height  with certain values, is still not working

Comment: Dear Vennox, you haven't set button's constraints like these for example:          `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84000003"`